# Проверка IAP подписки в Юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, in-app-purchases

Как проверить если юзер купил подписку и дать доступ к игре, игра на iOS, как получить информацию о статусе юзера (подписан или нет) или срок на который он подписан

П.С. Ни разу не делал покупку подписки или NonConsumable, извините если что не правильно.